# Why is request body sending values undefined or null to server side?

Tags: mysql, heroku, post, postman, server-side

Serverside code is using Heroku with clearDb addon.

POST request is using Postman:  See Screen shot:

Note that I am sending an JSON object with three string values.

[image]

This is the error I get:
[image]

This is the MYSQL table and columns

[image]

This is the js on the server-side for POST and the MYSQL query.  This is probably a simple answer, however, any help on this would really be appreciated.

```js
app.post('/' , (req,res) => {
    const {email, name, question} = req.body;
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    console.log(`Your Email is ${email} and your name is ${name} and your ${question}`);



//MYSQL updating table

pool.query("INSERT INTO customer_questions (name, email, question) VALUES (?,?,?)",
    [name, email, question], (err,result)=> {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
        }else {
            res.send('data sent')
        }
        
    }
    );


});
```

Comment: A good start is probably to set the Content-type header to application/json

Comment: Thanks, yap that was it.  Just need to change it from text to JSON and update the keys with double-quotes.  Really thanks for the second eye.

Answer (score 0):

Had to change the header type from text to JSON and update the key with double quotes.